How can I create numbered columns based on rows per identifier in a dataframe in Python?
I have a dataset that looks like this:
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'ID': ['Bob1','Jeff1','Sally2', 'Bob2','Bob1','Jeff1','Bob1','Willa5','Jeff1','Bob1','Sally2'], 'Dates': ['2024-01-10', '2024-08-28', '2024-07-03', '2024-02-05', '2024-01-28', '2024-02-19', '2024-04-01', '2024-07-22', '2024-09-27', '2024-06-06', '2024-01-11']})

I would like to create a new dataframe that takes each row and transforms the values into columns, while adding yet another column (Category) when the date column is created, like so (though the sorting is not important):



ID
Date1
Category1
Date2
Category2
Date3
Category3
Date4
Category4




Bob1
2024-01-10
1
2024-01-28
1
2024-04-01
1
2024-06-06
1


Bob2
2024-02-05
1
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan


Jeff1
2024-02-19
1
2024-09-27
1
nan
nan
nan
nan


Sally2
2024-01-11
1
2024-07-03
1
nan
nan
nan
nan


Willa5
2024-07-22
1
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan



I have found a way, using assign and lambda, to get the dates columns to generate:
df2 = df.groupby(by=['ID'])['Dates'].unique().to_frame().reset_index()
df3 = pd.concat([df2['ID'],df2['Dates'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([i for i in x])).pipe(lambda df4: df4.set_axis([f'Date{i}' for i in range(1, len(df4.columns)+1)],axis = 1))], axis = 1)

This works to get the dates to new columns, but I need to add the Category column each time a data column is created. How can I get this to work?

df['rank'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1
dates = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='rank', values='Dates')
categories = dates.mask(dates.notna(), 1)

out = pd.concat([dates.add_prefix('Date'), categories.add_prefix('Category')], axis=1).reset_index()

rank      ID       Date1       Date2       Date3       Date4 Category1 Category2 Category3 Category4
0       Bob1  2024-01-10  2024-01-28  2024-04-01  2024-06-06         1         1         1         1
1       Bob2  2024-02-05         NaN         NaN         NaN         1       NaN       NaN       NaN
2      Jeff1  2024-08-28  2024-02-19  2024-09-27         NaN         1         1         1       NaN
3     Sally2  2024-07-03  2024-01-11         NaN         NaN         1         1       NaN       NaN
4     Willa5  2024-07-22         NaN         NaN         NaN         1       NaN       NaN       NaN

